# EC2 instance outgoing http request rate limits

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm building a node application on EC2 that queries various external APIs several times per second via http requests.

I cannot work this out from the EC2 documentation - are there any EC2 rate limits for querying external APIs?

E.g. if I'm continuously making 2 or 3 http requests per second from an ec2 instance, will I start getting rate limit errors from ec2?

Thanks

Comment: ec2 does not care what you request from the inside.

Comment: great thank you . . . if you submit as answer I'll mark it off as the answer.  Thanks tons

Comment: 2 or 3 requests/sec is nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ec2 provides you the virtual machine and (if you configure it) the external connection.

Then it's totally up to you on what you query with it.

AWS provides you the layer 3 network which is charged by traffic amount, not number of requests.

Comment: can I suggest just for clarity for anyone else that might have the same question something like "AWS will not limit the number of outgoing requests made from an EC2 instance"